# Use Regex to find some match words in a line beginning with specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have input like following example:

```
Contact to Hwang
Contact to John, Peter in Newyork, Shara
```

Using Regex, how to get "Hwang", "John" "Peter, "Shara" for the result. The line always begin with "Contact to". The first value after "Contact to", other values seperated by commas without including location.

Any idea to solve my problem! Thank.

Comment: Strictly regex? Can you use some other methods? If so, what language?

Answer (score 0):

> The first value after "Contact to", other values seperated by commas without including location.

Try this:

```
/Contact to |(\w+?\b)[^,\n\r]*/gi
```

[image: regex]

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/iG1aT3/3

Comment: This is not entirely correct .It will match `,` sepearated words even if it is not after `contact to`